# ttk::label multiline formatting

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to display my lines like this :

```
Nombre de seq(s)     = 10
Nombre de page(s)    = 12
Fichier word         = c:/temp/word.docx
Fichier simulation   = c:/temp/word.tmp
```

but in my label my lines are displayed like this

[image]

How can I make my lines alligned to the equal sign

Below my code :

```
package require Tk

lappend info [format "%-20s = %-1s" "Nombre de seq(s)" 10]
lappend info [format "%-20s = %-1s" "Nombre de page(s)" 1]
lappend info [format "%-20s = %-1s" "Fichier word" {c:/temp/word.docx}]
lappend info [format "%-20s = %-1s" "Fichier simulation" {c:/temp/word.tmp}]

grid [ttk::label .l -text [join $info "\n"]] -row 0 -column 0 -padx 2 -pady 2 -sticky nw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to configure the label to use a fixed font.

If you want a proportional font, then you could split things up into 8 separate labels and put those in a grid.

To use a proportional font **and** only one label, you can play with the different with spaces available in unicode:

```
set data {
    "Nombre de seq(s)" 10
    "Nombre de page(s)" 12
    "Fichier word" "c:/temp/word.docx"
    "Fichier simulation" "c:/temp/word.tmp"
}

# Put the different size spaces in a dict
set spaces [dict create [font measure TkDefaultFont " "] " "]
for {set i 0x2000} {$i <= 0x200a} {incr i} {
    set s [format %c $i]
    dict set spaces [font measure TkDefaultFont $s] $s
}
# A 0-width space could cause an endless loop
dict unset spaces 0
# Sort the dict to be able to use a bisect lsearch
set spaces [lsort -integer -index 0 -stride 2 $spaces]

# Calculate the sizes of the lefthand terms and find the longest
set sizes [lmap n [dict keys $data] {font measure TkDefaultFont $n}]
set max [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$sizes]

set txt [lmap s [dict keys $data] l $sizes {
    set v [dict get $data $s]
    # Keep adding the biggest space that will fit
    # until the string is the same length as the longest one
    while {$l < $max} {
        set w [expr {$max - $l}]
        set key [lsearch -inline -integer -bisect [dict keys $spaces] $w]
        append s [dict get $spaces $key]
        incr l $key
    }
    # Append the value
    append s " = " $v
}]

# Combine the lines and show them on a label
ttk::label .l -text [join $txt \n]
grid .l
```

Additional checks or a more intelligent algorithm may be needed if the font doesn't have any 1-pixel space.

Answer (score 1):

The label widgets are not really designed for this sort of thing. You could use a fixed width font, or you could try inserting tabs:

```
pack [ttk::label .l -textvariable foo]

# Doing this directly rather than computing it
set foo "Nombre de seq(s)\t\t= 10
Nombre de page(s)\t= 12
Fichier word\t\t= c:/temp/word.docx
Fichier simulation\t\t= c:/temp/word.tmp"
```

Tabs are a bit tricky here because the disparity between line lengths is a bit too much for them to automatically hide.

The best alternative though is probably to use a read-only text widget, as that widget lets you have *exact* control over layout.

```
pack [text .t -font TkDefaultFont]

.t insert 1.0 "Nombre de seq(s)\t= 10
Nombre de page(s)\t= 12
Fichier word\t= c:/temp/word.docx
Fichier simulation\t= c:/temp/word.tmp"

.t configure -tabs [font measure TkDefaultFont "Nombre de page(s) "] -state disabled
# You MUST insert the text before disabling the widget.
```

(You'll need to experiment with how to get the overall widget width right. And with what colour to set the background to.)